# How to install Qt designer for pyside development if you already have Ubuntu sdk?

Tags: qt, ubuntu-sdk

I have ubuntu sdk installed on my machine. I'm interested in exploring pyside.
Some of the pyside tutorials tell us to use Qt designer (I would like to). And I know it can run outside the Ubuntu SDK. Is it possible to have both the Ubuntu SDK and Qt designer installed on Ubuntu 16.04 without causing dependency problems?

Or in other words, how do I install Qt designer without messing the Ubuntu SDK (which I also would like to use).

Answer (score 0):

install this package:

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-designer
```